# Partial View Submit inside Parent View MVC 3 w/Razor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have three partial views that I load into a div based on radio button selection using jquery. Everything works fine on the loading and on the forms, however each partial form has a submit button(none on the parent form). I begin each partial form with:

```
    <div id="newTicketPartial">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateNewTicket", "SubmitTicket", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "newTicketPartial", HttpMethod = "POST" }))
```

The issue is that within this form once I finish entering data and click the submit button it seems to skip this forms ajax post back header and instead uses the parent views @using Html.BeginForm
If I put an action and controller in the parent forms BeginForm field it will use that, otherwise there is an error. My problem is even if it does use the parent views POST path my controller only returns the partial view that I was editing, which updates the entire page. I need to be able to submit information from each partial view and have only that partial view be updated, not the entire page. I am open to suggestions of ways this can be done. If more code is desired I will post more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested forms are the issue. You should not nest forms, or else any buttons further down the page (even those generated by partial views) will cause the parent form to POST.

Comment: This was what I suspected, I have decided to add my own submit buttons to each partial view that use ajax to update their partial view.